# Php. Распарсить xml

Tags: xml, xmlparser, синтаксический-анализ

Привет всем. Есть код:

```
if($xml = $xmlDoc->xpath('//RLS[@PREFIX="http://"]')) {
  foreach($xml as $node) {
    foreach($node as $n) {
    $a = (array) $n->attributes();
    $test6['HREF'][] =  $a['@attributes']['HREF'];
    }
  }
}

print_r($test6);
```

Выводит информацию таким образом:

```
Array ( [HREF] => Array ( [0] => amazon.com/ [1] => wikipedia.org/ [2] => www.yahoo.com/ [3] => youtube.com/ [4] => yelp.com/ [5] => statcounter.com/ [6] => myspace.com/ [7] => linkedin.com/ [8] => imdb.com/ [9] => google.co.in/ [10] => ask.com/ ) )
```

Как сделать, чтобы информацию выводило так:

```
<a href="http://amazon.com" target="_blank">amazon.com</a>
```

Также было бы неплохо, если бы показывались только первые 5 или 6 доменов.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$links = array(); // всегда заранее объявляйте массив, если не хотите потом ловить предупреждения на продакшене
if ($xml = $xmlDoc->xpath('//RLS[@PREFIX="http://"]')) {
    foreach ($xml as $node) {
        foreach ($node as $n) {
            $attrs = (array) $n->attributes();
            $link = rtrim($attrs['@attributes']['HREF'], '/');
            $bits = explode('/', $link);
            $host = $bits[0];
            $host = str_replace('www.', '', $host); // очень грубо, но будет работать
            $links[] =  $host;
        }
    }
}

// вывод
// устанавливаем, сколько ссылок нам нужно
$limit = 6;
for ($i = 0; $i < $limit; $i++) { ?>
    <a href="http://<?php echo $links[$i]; ?>">
         <?php echo $links[$i]; ?>
    </a>
<?php }
```

Где-то мог ошибиться, не тестировал код.

Comment: Спасибо, все работает хорошо, но есть одно "но".

Пример: www.parentsalready.com/test

Как обрезать, чтобы не было (www.), и обрезать все, что есть после (/)?